# Как не застревать в маленьких отступах в Construct 2?

Tags: разработка-игр, construct-2

Если игрок упирается в маленький отступ (буквально 4 пикселя) то он дальше двинуться не может, нужно прыгать чтоб пройти дальше

[image: что-то типа такого]

Как исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Исправил - надо добавить на объект этот модуль:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]